# XML formatting not passing through thanks to XSLT issue

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I need to edit a transform we've got that changes DITA XML to a slightly different version of XML for our learning management system. Here's my problem: when I run the transform, I'm losing formatting in certain file type titles, even though it works in other file types titles. For example, when I create a summary file, u passes through in the  just fine, but in a concept file, the u drops out. I've tried just about everything I can think of, but no dice. The problem seems to be that for concepts, I can pull in a navtitle from my map, but I can't with the other types (and this is a requirement for all file types, so once this is fixed, I'll need to apply it to everything).

I have this code listed in a "common" section that works with the summary, etc, types:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="new_tt_common">
   <xsl:param name="prefix" select="''"/>
 <title>
    <xsl:value-of select="$prefix"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="identity" xml:space="default"/>
 </title>
</xsl:template>
```

This accurately passes through any elements contained in title.

This code is for concepts:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$navtitle = ''">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="new_tt_common"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <title>
            <xsl:value-of select="$navtitle"/>
        </title>
            </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I have $navtitle defined earlier in the code correctly, I believe, as it is working fine. There's something about this chunk of code that is not correct and it's driving me nuts. Basically, if there is no navtitle, the title should become the title in the new file. If there is a navtitle, that should become the title in the new file.

Here are some samples of my input. This is my chapter map:

```
<topicref href="../topics/re_intro_1.dita" locktitle="yes" navtitle="Case Study: Reselling a Condo"/>
<topicref href="../topics/re_los_1.dita"/>
```

The title in re_intro_1.dita:

```
<title><tm tmtype="reg">Introduction</tm> Testing</title>
```

The title in re_los_1.dita:

```
<title>Learning <i>Objective</i></title>
```

In this instance, I want the title of the first file to be "Case Study: Reselling a Condo and the second file to be Learning *Objective*. Currently, the title text is coming through fine, but I'm losing the italics on Objective.

Anybody have any ideas why the elements contained in title aren't coming through?

Comment: Best to edit your Q to include sample inputs, otherwise people have to guess what might be wrong there. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please post the complete samples like complete XML, complete XSLT, and the complete expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your otherwise to be an apply-templates rather than a value-of. That should pass the italics for further processing.

Comment: I changed it to this (sorry, I can't figure out how to make code look correct in a comment):

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$navtitle = ''">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="new_tt_common"/>
</xsl:when>
                 </xsl:choose> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[contains(@class,' topic/title ')]" mode="new_tt_common">
                <xsl:with-param name="navtitle" select="$navtitle"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>

but had no luck. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @PeytonBentley : Its best to add another section to you question, so people can follow the thread. People use a separator line, and the word EDIT in bold. Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box. The separator tool and Bold tool are also there. Briefly describe the change you made and why (but the code is the more important thing). If you get any output, include it, labeled separately and include verbatim any error messages you get. With very little work, readers should be able recreate your input doc&code and get the same results that  you are. *Then* they can help. Good luck